# D3.js updating the code, Error: Cannot read property 'axis' of undefined?

Tags: d3.js

D3.js has updated and I have no idea how to how to change this old code into the new version. Thank you.

Here is the code.

```
   function renderAxes(svg) {
            var axesG = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axes");
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(_x.range([0, quadrantWidth()]))
                    .orient("bottom");
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(_y.range([quadrantHeight(), 0]))
                    .orient("left");
            axesG.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axis")
                    .attr("transform", function () {
                        return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yStart() + ")";
                    })
                    .call(xAxis);
            axesG.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "axis")
                    .attr("transform", function () {
                        return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yEnd() + ")";
                    })
                    .call(yAxis);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear *where* you are trying to put the axes because we don't know what `xStart()`, `yStart()`, `quadrantWidth()` etc. are.

But the errors you are getting are because D3 has updated the functions to create axes. Instead of `d3.svg.axix()`, we now have: `d3.axisLeft()`, `d3.axisBottom()`, etc. Creating scales is different too. It's not clear in your code what `_x` and `_y` are or how they are created, so the code below just makes new scales.

This should make the errors go away, but may still need updating to put things in the right spot.:

```
function renderAxes(svg) {
  var axesG = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axes");

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, quadrantWidth()])

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([quadrantHeight(), 0])

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

  axesG.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", function () {
              return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yStart() + ")";
          })
          .call(xAxis);
  axesG.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis")
          .attr("transform", function () {
              return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yEnd() + ")";
          })
          .call(yAxis);
```

}

Comment: Thank you for answer, it helped. Sorry for my bad question. I just started.